# Value of type "ViewController" has no member 'ref' with Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ref

I am trying to write data to the realtime database with Firebase, however I have done this correctly in the past - but I cannot seem to get it working.  Here is the function that is producing the error that I am recieving:

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        self.ref.child("user").child(user.uid).setValue(["test": "test"])
}
```

which is producing the error:

```
Value of type "DailyVC" has no member 'ref'
```

I have tried reading for advice here and on the documentation profusely but cannot seem to fix this error.  Thanks.

***edit:***
I tried removing the 'self' at the beginning of the last line, however this resulted in the following error:

```
Type 'user' has no member 'uid'
```

Which is equally confusing me.

Comment: Replace `self.ref.child...` with `ref.child...`. `self.ref` does not exist.

Comment: what it type of `user `

Comment: @shallowThought I tried this, and in the edit I added - a new error has bene produced which I don't understand either, thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

`user` type should be `FIRUser` if you want to access its `uid` property.

And Refer [THIS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRUser) and [THIS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Protocols/FIRUserInfo) documentation for more Info about `FIRUser`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided how you declared the 'user' variable, but I have done this and it works. Also since the database reference isn't going to change you should consider changing it to a constant.

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser else { return }

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.child("user").child(user.uid).setValue(["test": "test"])
}
```

This is a screenshot of it successfully being saved to the database.

[image: Screenshot of this data being saved to the database]